# Swift map compile error

Tags: swift

Below is my swift function to calculate the sum of multiples of a given set of real numbers in a range from 0 to 'upto'. The algorithm loops through from 1 to the upper limit and maps the array of multiples to an array of modulos for the specified multipliers and then reduces that array using multiplication such that if a given value of i is evenly divisible by any of the given multipliers the result of the reduce will be 0.

```
func sumOfMultiples(mults: [Int], upto: Int) -> {
  var acc: Int = 0
  for i in 1...upto {
      if mults.map({i % $0}).reduce(1,*) == 0 {
          acc += i
      }
  }
  return acc
}
```

The problem is I'm getting a compile error

```
 error: 'Int' is not a subtype of '()'
    if mults.map({i % 0}).reduce(1,*) == 0 {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Methinks you're missing this:        ~~~~~~~~vvv
func sumOfMultiples(mults: [Int], upto: Int) -> Int {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func sumOfMultiples(mults: [Int], upto: Int) -> {
  var acc: Int = 0
  for i in 1...upto {
    if mults.map( { (x) in i % x } ).reduce(1,*) == 0 {
      acc += i
    }
  }
  return acc
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. You forgot the return value (like the OP). Please also add a short sentence what you changes (though it's almost obvious)